# Why does adding export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='myproject.settings' to bashrc no longer work?

Tags: linux, django, celery, django-celery

I have a Django app running on a linux machine (Debian). For the past little while the app has run perfectly. Recently I needed to reboot the machine after celery tasks started to hang and purging the tasks didn't have the desired effect. When I now attempt to start celery using

```
sudo celery -A myapp.tasks worker -Ofair
```

I am presented with the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('celery==3.1.11', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 769, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 304, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 464, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 484, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 225, in find_app
    sym = imp(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/this/gce_app/myapp/tasks.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware, get_token
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import get_cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must
 either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing set
tings.
```

I have added the export to bashrc (at the end) which fixed the problem in the past, but now I am still presented with the same error:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='myproject.settings'
```

Is there a way to get this working again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're starting celery with sudo, which means you're running as the root user, not the one you set the environment variable for. Don't do that - there's absolutely no good reason to run the daemon with sudo.

(And not related to your problem, but you shouldn't be editing bashrc as sudo either.)

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, because I had to think about this for a bit, the ~ in the `sudo nano ~/.bashrc` is expanded before sudo is called, so ~ still refers to the original user, not the root user.

Comment: Daniel - thanks for this, you were absolutely correct! Running the same command sans the sudo encountered no errors. You have no idea how many hours I spent trying to get this working before posting here :s